# Azure Payment Support

Tags: azure

I was hosting a Parse web app that was only being used by myself, so I didn't use many resources (I think it was $7 total) and the free trial has run out. Now I would like to hire a freelancer to implement existing database implementations with an API endpoint.

Now to get my app up and running again, I have to activate the Pay-as-you-go, but I don't want to be copped with a huge bill at the end of the month from the freelancer, as he would have access to my account and could do whatever he would like.

My question here is what do you suggest I do in this situation? Is there a small monthly subscription with limited resources I could use or something? Or should I make another trial account?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now to get my app up and running again, I have to activate the
>   Pay-as-you-go, but I don't want to be copped with a huge bill at the
>   end of the month from the freelancer, as he would have access to my
>   account and could do whatever he would like.

At first, I thought you could enforce spending limits on your `Pay-as-you-go` subscription but after reading [`this`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn465781.aspx), I realized it is not possible for this kind of subscription.

Here would be my recommendation to avoid any billing surprises:

- **Don't give your freelancer complete access to your Azure Subscription**: With [`Azure Role-based access control (RBAC)`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-configure/) you can define granular permissions on the resources and grant your freelancer only the permissions he/she absolutely need to manage your application. One idea here would be to start by putting this freelancer in `Reader` role at the Subscription level and identify the blockers which is preventing him/her to do the work. Gradually start removing these blockers. Now that Azure supports custom roles, it makes your job to grant them really granular permissions on the resources that they absolutely need. For example, you could create a mobile service and grant this freelancer in `Contributor` role just on that mobile service (yes, you can do that!). That way, the user can't create new mobile services. I haven't looked at all the permissions that can be granted on a mobile service resource but I would strongly encourage you to take a look at them and when you define your custom role, simply yank out the permissions you don't want to give to this freelance developer.
- **Keep an eye out on the usage**: I would strongly recommend keeping an eye out on the usage. When you login into Azure Portal, you can check the usage and approximate bill for your subscription. I would recommend doing it on a daily basis. You can also set up [`billing alerts`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/billing-set-up-alerts/) so that you get notified if the usage goes above threshold.

Comment: Thank you so much.